# Почему вылетает код?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть `EditText` в который юзер устанавливает ответы. Суть в том, что когда юзер заканчивает тест `EditText` должен очиститься. Но когда я делаю `editText.setText(" ");` программа вылетает... Я уже как только не пробовал не понимаю почему вылетает и пишет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я в коде отметил строчку в которой вылетает... Что я делаю не так?

**Вот код :**

```
public class CheckABC extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnKeyListener {
private int finish;
private int mistake;
private int number;
private boolean stopWhile;
private Button bStart;
private Button bCheck;
private Context context;
private Chronometer chronometer;
private ImageView ivOutput;
private ArrayList<com.example.tanya_.learnhebrew.generals.Letters> array;
private EditText etInputLatter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_yourself);
    array = Letters.getInstance().getLetterses();
    context = this;
    etInputLatter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddLetter);

    etInputLatter.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                checkYourself();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public void startCheck(View v) {
    etInputLatter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    bCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
    (bCheck).setEnabled(true);

    bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
    bStart.setEnabled(false);
    startCheck();
}

private void startChronometer() {
    chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    chronometer.start();
}

private void startCheck() {
    startChronometer();
    new StartCheck().start();
}

private int[] mesInitializing(int arraySize) {
    int[] mes = new int[arraySize];
    for (int i = 0; i < mes.length; i++) {
        mes[i] = -1;
    }
    return mes;
}

private class StartCheck extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int[] mes = mesInitializing(array.size());

        boolean check = true;
        finish = 0;
        int i = 0;

        while (finish < array.size()) {

            number = (int) (Math.random() * array.size());

            for (int obj : mes) {
                check = number != obj;
                if (!check) break;
            }

            if (check) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println(number);
                        ivOutput = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivLetter);
                        ivOutput.setImageResource(
                                array.get(number).getIdIRForPropis());
                    }
                });

                mes[i] = number;
                i += 1;
                while (!stopWhile) {
                    try {
                        sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                stopWhile = false;
            }
        }

        if (finish == array.size()) {
            chronometer.stop();
            final long totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(totalTime);
            final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ivOutput.setImageDrawable(null);
                    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());


------>>>>  ВОТ ЭТА СТРОЧКА      etInputLatter.setText(" ");



                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CheckABC.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Results!")
                            .setMessage("Your mistake " + mistake + "\n" + " Your time " +
                                    format.format(cal.getTime()) + "\n" + "Do you want try again?")
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.goodresult)
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setNegativeButton("I want try again!",
                                    new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            startCheck();
                                        }
                                    })
                            .setPositiveButton("Cancel ",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                    bStart.setEnabled(true);
                    bCheck.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

public void checkYourself(View v) {
    checkYourself();
}

private void checkYourself(){
    String inputLatter = etInputLatter.getText().toString();
    String vvodSKlavi = array.get(number).getVvodSKlavi();

    if (inputLatter.isEmpty())
        Toast.makeText(context, "enter you answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else {
        if (vvodSKlavi.equals(inputLatter)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "you are right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            etInputLatter.setText("");
            finish += 1;
            this.stopWhile = true;
        }
        if (!inputLatter.equals(vvodSKlavi)) {
            mistake += 1;
            Toast.makeText(context, "try one more", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            etInputLatter.setText("");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return false;
}

public void backToABC(View v) {
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: Это не проблема editext, у вас в потоке происходит утечка памяти.

Comment: Но когда я комменчу эту строчку то все работает нормально... Но если это утечка, как это исправить? Я новичок и не совсем понимаю где утечка?

Comment: То что это утечка вам пишет стек лога, который вы выложили. Сейчас почитаю код и отвечу вам как исправить.

Comment: Я бы организовал вашу задачу не через Thread, а AsynkTask. Я так понимаю вы используйте поток, что бы в цикле у вас менялись image's ?

Comment: да все верно... да точно... Можно исправить на AsynkTask... Он вроде более стабильный. Вы думаете это исправит ситуацию?

Comment: Он значительно оптимизирует ваш код) также вам не нужно будет запускать run() для слипа. Реализируете AsynkTask, если будут ошибки отпишити помогу)

Comment: ок, спасибо! Сейчас займусь и отпишу

Comment: Поток-то вам зачем? Насколько я понимаю, программа последовательно что-то показывает пользователю, ждет, пока пользователь ответит на вопрос и нажмет кнопку, и так пока у программы вопросы не кончатся? Просто заведите список вопросов, индекс текущего вопроса, и по нажатию на кнопку ответа показывайте пользователю следующий.

Comment: Да я сначала так и сделал, но у меня не менялась картика... То есть юзеру показывается картика, он угадывает что это , нажимает кнопку проверить, идет проверка и если верно, то показывается следующая картика, так вот до тех пор пока я не сделал это потоком картика первая показывалась, а дальше ничего не менялось, хотя программа бежала дальше, но UI почему то не обновлялся

Comment: Т.е. раньше у вас все содержимое `run` было в обработчике нажатия на кнопку?

Comment: Ну скорее всего да, просто уже много времени прошло с тех пор как я исправил я не помню точно. Вы думаете можно и вовсе без потока обойтись?

Comment: Тут человек говорит, что можно вовсе без потока обойтись... Как вы считаете?

Comment: Если вы хотите в цикле менять фото, то без потока или AsynkTask никак

Comment: Вам надо задавать следующий вопрос после того, как пользователь правильно ответил на текущий. Пользователь отвечает на вопрос нажатием кнопки. Если введен правильный ответ, то если вопросы еще есть, вы достаете и показываете следующий. Если вопросы кончились - показываете результаты. Цикл не нужен, поток не нужен, ожидание нажатия кнопки не нужно.

Comment: А как же я тогда смогу без цикла поочередно достать все вопросы из `ArrayList`? У меня все вопросы лежат в списке...Я не знаю другого способа как ни циклом? А как еще? Я вижу это так программа циклом достает вопрос, ждет ввода, проверяет его, если верно то бежит дальше по циклу и показывает следующий вопрос. А как вы это видите?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko для начала заведите список с текущими вопросами, как поле класса вашей активити. В `startCheck` вы его заполняете, перемешиваете `Collections.shuffle` и т.п. Дальше либо заводите поле с индексом текущего вопроса и увеличиваете индекс, когда пользователь ответил, либо считаете текущим первый элемент списка, и удаляете первый элемент из списка после ответа. Когда индекс превышает размер списка (или список пуст) - тест закончен.

Comment: Да, ок, но это отработает только один раз... Так как код будет бежать, попадает в первый метод {создаст список, перемешает его, установит первый вопрос}, пойдет дальше второй метод который прикреплен к кнопке `Check` {Возьмет ответ юзера из `EditText`, сравнит его с верным и если все верно то мы увеличим элемент списка на 1}, вопрос поменяется на следующий и все код закончит свое выполнение... Что заставит его повторить это выполнение? Я так понимаю цикл, но тогда как цикл будет ждать пока пользователь сделает ввод и нажмет  `Check`? Могу приложить код для наглядности http://ideone.com/DenUP6

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko как-то так http://pastebin.com/jWx162L7

Comment: Точно! Спасибо! Я понял.... Блин как я сразу не подумал...